# Docker image is very large when including a small node library

Tags: docker, expo

I'm building a custom Docker image for use in CI. It's based on Node Alpine, and only includes git and the node CLI for publishing the app, `expo-cli` - but the resulting image takes up 1.27GB of space.

This is the CLI
https://github.com/expo/expo-cli

The corresponding folder in my `node_modules` is 16.4 MB

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN set -xe \
  && apk add --no-cache git \yarn -v
  && git --version && node -v && yarn -v

RUN yarn global add expo-cli@2.18.3
```

The build context itself is tiny:

```
docker build . -t no-unsafe
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/4 : FROM node:alpine
...
```

Using [Dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) to analyze the image, it says that `RUN yarn global add expo-cli@2.18.3` adds 1.1GB to the image:

[image: The layers]

Inspecting that layer specifically shows the following folders to be the culprit

[image]

I don't understand how this image ends up so huge?

Comment: Are `.cache` and `.config` necessary folders? Could you try to remove them in the same step as `yarn global add expo-cli@2.18.3` and still use the resulting base image without any errors? It may be some cache yarn uses when downloading/installing, something like `apt-get update` does (I'm not a yarn specialist, but this may be worth trying).

Comment: What’s so hard to understand? Just clear npm cache after the install.